# How can I make N copies of the same model and train separately?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I have a simple fully connected model as below,

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Lambda,

def ModelX(m): 

    hidden1 = 8
    hidden2 = 8
    hidden3 = 8

    model_input = layers.Input(shape=(2,))
    hidden_layer1 = Dense(hidden1, activation='relu')(model_input)
    hidden_layer2 = Dense(hidden2, activation='relu')(hidden_layer1)
    hidden_layer3 = Dense(hidden3, activation='relu')(hidden_layer2)
    model_output = Dense(m, activation='linear')(hidden_layer3)
    modelx = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=model_output)

    return modelX
```

I have an input data sequence of length `(2, N)`. I want to have an `N`length array of ModelX,  so that each `(2,1)` slice of the input sequence is the input to each model. Finally, outputs of these models are to be concatenated together to make a `4N` length sequence.

PS: `keras.layers.TimeDistributed()` is not what I am expecting. I want to input each slice of the input to different copies of the same model and train them separately. How can I achieve this?

This is what I have done so far,

```
def Model_Array(Config): 
    N = Config.N
    y = layers.Input(shape=(2,N,))


    for i in range(N):
        x_input = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, i])(y)

        if i == 0:
           x_output = Modelx(Config.m)(x_input)
        else:
            x_output = layers.concatenate([x_output,
                                           Modelx(Config.m)(x_input)])

    x_output = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :tf.cast(N, tf.int32)])(x_output)

    output = SomeOtherModel(Config)(x_output)
    output = Lambda(lambda x: K.sigmoid(-x))(output)

    model = Model(y, output)
    return model
```

But this model does not give intended performance

Comment: What isn't working about the code you included?

Comment: Also: your function is `ModelX`, and in the function you create a variable `modelx`, but then you return `ModelX`, and call a function named `Modelx`. Can you edit your code to include the correct capitalization for these names?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Sorry about that. Fixed the mistake. This model does not train well and I am not sure whether it does what I intended to do.